# Programming a simple Game,

Tags: c++, directx

Hey im programming a simple game using directX and C++ and i have hit a slight problem which im sure some genius can fix.

I currently have an array of 8 Aliens and i currently use this code to move them left to right and down a line.

```
bool turnaround=false;
if ((Aliens[0].pos.x<-5 & Aliens[0].vel.x<0)|(Aliens[3].pos.x>5&Aliens[3].vel.x>0))
{
    turnaround=true;
    if(Aliens[0].vel.x<0)
        Aliens[0].animCtrl->SetTrackSpeed(0,1);
    else
        Aliens[0].animCtrl->SetTrackSpeed(0,-1);
}
```

However this currently stops them short if ones to the left or right have been destroyed (they are destroyed by a variable `Aliens[i].dead = true`

I was wondering if anyone can come up with the if statement or nested if's required to say if ones furthest left or right are destroyed go further across :/

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you purposefully using a bitwise OR (`|`) instead of a logical OR (`||`) (same goes for AND)?  I don't think you are.  Also... `vector<T>` is your friend :)

Comment: Do you  mean to be using a binary `|` and `&` operator or a logical `||` and `&&`?

Comment: There are several issues with your code: why are you not using a for loop iterating over an `Alien` list? Why are you using a `.dead` attribute instead of just deleting them from such list?

Comment: There are some cases where a `.dead` attribute could be useful - i.e. if an enemy needs to destroy itself for some reason, it could set this parameter so a manager class knows to clean it up. (bad for it to destroy itself with `delete this;`). - but in this scenario it does seem unnecessary, you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume from your question that you are constructing some sort of space invaders type game. Here would be one way to approach this that might be better than what you currently have (in a pseudo-code form):

```
For each alien:
  If alien is currently on an odd row:
    Set direction to left
    If alien x position is near 0:
       Set direction to down
  Else
    Set direction to right
    If alien x position is near screen width:
       Set direction to down
```

This should cause the aliens to move down towards the bottom of the screen row by row. (Of course there are many different formations aliens could take in this type of game, this is just one). You aren't clear about what sort of behaviour you want them to exhibit when they are killed ("go further across" is ambiguious, is this the player or some of the aliens, or what?), however, if you elaborate on that I may be able to lend further advice here.

I would also suggest you reconsider your design for a minute. You have what appears to be a fixed size array that holds the 8 aliens. While this may allow you to construct a particular level, it is likely to prove very restrictive. What if in another level you want 12 aliens? I suggest you turn your `Aliens` array into an `std::vector`, so you can add them to a level as you like at will. Even better, if you have different types of enemies that all share the same properties, you could create a superclass `CEnemy` that these enemies all inherit from. This is likely to make your design more robust and expandable.

Also, as has been stated by others already, use logical operators when you want to run an `AND` or `OR` operation, not bitwise. (That is, use `||` instead of `|`, etc) There is an important difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you should get in the habit of using the logical operators (`&&` and `||`) for things like this instead of bitwise operators.  They should be more efficient because of short circuiting and prevent bugs later down the road.

I'm not sure if there's enough information to answer your real question.  Why are you manually accessing the 0th and 3rd Alien?  How do you want the aliens to behave, ideally?

**EDIT 1:**

Something like this should work:

```
Alien * furthestLeftAlien, * furthestRightAlien;
/** here loop through your Aliens array to find
    the furthest left and furthest right aliens **/
if(furthestLeftAlien->dead || furthestRightAlien->dead)
{
    goFurtherAcross():
}
```

Comment: *furthestRightAlien... don't forget the *

Comment: @Bingo thanks, I guess that's the problem with declaring multiple variables on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using a different data structure altogether.  C++ std library has several different container classes that can help you.

For instance, a std::deque allows you to easily remove items from either end.

You could remove dead aliens like:

```
while (!Aliens.empty() && Aliens.front().is_dead()) Aliens.pop_front();
while (!Aliens.empty() && Aliens.back().is_dead()) Aliens.pop_back();
```

And then your code above would go:

```
bool turnaround=false;
if ((Aliens.front().pos.x<-5 && Aliens.front().vel.x<0) || (Aliens.back().pos.x>5 && Aliens.back().vel.x>0))
{
    turnaround=true;
    if(Aliens.front().vel.x<0)
        Aliens.front().animCtrl->SetTrackSpeed(0,1);
    else
        Aliens.front().animCtrl->SetTrackSpeed(0,-1);
}
```

Though to be honest, I'm not sure how the code here is meant to turn around the whole row of aliens.  Instead of using a turnaround variable, why not just turn the aliens around inside the if statement?